# Html - Space Key Press is Causing OnClick to be Triggered

Tags: html, onclick, modal-dialog, space

[Note: this flaw only occurs in Internet Explorer 11. It is fine in IE9, Chrome and Firefox.]

I have the following Css:

```
/*** pop-up div to cover entire area ***/
.divModalDialog  {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*! important !*/
    display:none;
    /* last attribute set darkness on scale: 0...1.0 */
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    text-align:center;
    z-index:101;
}

/*** ! target attribute does the job ! ***/
.divModalDialog:target  { display:block; }
```

An Html:

```
<div id="divModalDialogUpdate" class="divModalDialog">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="divModalText" />
        <button onclick="doStuff();">Press</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divCanvas" style="display: none; width:100%; height: 100%;">
    <canvas id="m_Canvas" width="200" height="200" oncontextmenu="return false;"></canvas>
</div>
```

As you can see, I am using the divModalDialog as a Modal Dialog Box which appears over the canvas div.

On the canvas div, a game is running. When I need to fire up the modal dialog I pause the game and then have the code:

```
window.location = "#divModalDialogUpdate";
```

The person enters some stuff in the text box, clicks the button which triggers the onclick event which runs the function doStuff(). Within doStuff() is the following line of code which returns to just the canvas div being visible:

```
window.location = "#";
```

This works all great.

Now the problem. The game state is paused, and my prefered key to toggle the pause state is the Space key. (Any other key and things would be fine, but the problem is I want to use the space key).

So I tap the space key and this is (unwantedly) triggering the onclick event of the button in the modal dialog div **again** (even though the modal div is no longer visible) which obviously calls the doStuff() function again.

How do I stop the space key triggering the Modal Div's button onclick event when the Modal Div is no longer visible?

Comment: You could replace onclick with onmousedown, but then it wouldn't work on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a global variable `ignore` before any logic in `doStuff()`, e.g.,

```
function doStuff() {
    if(ignore == true) return;
    /* logic here ... */
}
```

Then change your other code to something like:

```
ignore = false;
window.location = "#divModalDialogUpdate";
```

and

```
ignore = true;
window.location = "#";
```

There might be a way to do this using `event.stopPropagation()` but I could not find a way to make that work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like I will have to use this. I have even looked for other stuff like currentStyle, but that only exists in IE. I was hoping for something cross browser, rather than a flag which keeps on needing to be changed by me. I'll leave the question open a little longer, but this looks like it will be the answer. Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: Might have found something in jquery, namely $("#divModalDialogUpdate").is(":visible"). So basically do what you have said replacing the update flag with the jquery check. Thanks again. I'll leave it open a bit longer just in case anyone can think of a way of stopping the space key trigger before onclick even gets fired.

Comment: Sure. I'm also interested if anyone has the event-fu skills to do it :)